# Validation not to submit an empty object with form-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash, redux-form

Please see my example: https://codesandbox.io/s/qzm5q6xvx4

I can add and remove fields on my form. When initialised the form has the submission button disabled as it uses 'pristine' that looks for form changes.

The problem is, when I add a field and then remove that field so there are no fields remaining the submission button is available to submit even though there is not data added - it sees the form no longer as 'pristine' and the json output is:

```
{
  "firstName": []
}
```

where ideally this needs to go back to `undefined` in order for the form to be pristine or I need some sort of check/validation on the submission. I thought these was one but cant see it. Prisite looks for json changes I think and I think this is where the problem is.

I am using react, redux-form, lodash.

Comment: i think that  when you submit the value the page will be realoaded so it lost all informations and it'll we reinitialised

Comment: I asked it to reset on submission. The point is it should not get this far as there is no data to submit, only the empty object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to solve my issue, I passed an empty object of firstName to the component -

`initialValues={{firstName: []}`

So the form now starts with the empty object therefore keeping the form `pristine` if a field gets created and then removed.

You do this by using the redux-form `initialValues` prop.

https://codesandbox.io/s/1o82695rr4